# POST request based on array of GET requests

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, axios

I have array of customers and addresses endpoint URL as below

```
  customerArray = [
  {name:customer1, id: 1, address: {streetName: '123 lane'}}, 
  {name:customer2, id: 2, address: {streetName: 'xyz lane'}}, 
  {name:customer3, id: 3, address: {streetName: 'abc lane'}}
]
URL = 'id/addresses'
```

GET request for URL will return array of addresses based on customer ID
if we get empty array as response then we need to add address from "customerArray" for that id

```js
 // This is what I am doing to meet the requirement - seems this is not the right approach. Please help me to fix this
customerArray.forEach((customer) => {
  const getObj = {
    url: `${customer.id}/addresses`,
    method: GET
  };

  axios(getObj)
    .then((getResult) => {
      if (getResult.length === 0) {
        const postObj = {
          url: `${customer.id}/addresses`,
          method: POST,
          data: customer.address
        };
        axios(postObj)
          .then((postResult) => {

            // I am not sure what to do here - I leaving blank so iteration will continue
          })
          .catch((err) => {
            res.status(400).json(err);
          });
      }
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      res.status(400).json(err);
    });

});
```

Please help me to fix it

Comment: What's the problem here and what do you want to fix ?

Comment: Getting unhandled exception error -

Comment: exception errors are usually tracable - which line of code throws the exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you don't know how to get the final data. Basically, you should put your promises into an array and you `Promise.all` to wait for all of them to finish.

Please comment if something wrong. Hope this helps

```
const promises = customerArray.map((customer) => {
  const getObj = {
    url: `${customer.id}/addresses`,
    method: GET
  };

  return axios(getObj)
    .then((getResult) => {
      if (getResult.length === 0) {
        return {
          url: `${customer.id}/addresses`,
          method: POST,
          data: customer.address
        };
      }
      return null;
    })
    .then((postObj) => {
      if (postObj) {
        return axios(postObj)
      }
      return null
    })
});

Promise.all(promises)
  .then(result => {
    // the result is a list of data from axios(postObj)
    console.log(result);
    res.json(result);
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    res.status(400).json(err);
  });
```

Comment: @JaromandaX Just want to demonstrate more clearly. I removed it.

Comment: @JaromandaX I don't think It's poor code. You use then after that, It means you expect a promise to return. However, with the magic of JS, you can still return an object. I worked with a lot of guys getting confused about that. That's why I want to put a Promise.resolve(null) at first to let people understand it easily.

Comment: @Dat Tran yeah I agree with your approach